# How to make a client component Next.js 13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, headless-ui

I'm trying to turn a 3rd party component into a client component. Here is how nextjs [does it](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/rendering/server-and-client-components#third-party-packages)

**Official Next.js Example**

app/carousel.js

```
'use client';

import { AcmeCarousel } from 'acme-carousel';

export default AcmeCarousel;
```

app/page.js

```
import Carousel from './carousel';

export default function Page() {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>View pictures</p>

      {/*  Works, since Carousel is a Client Component */}
      <Carousel />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**My code**

ClientPopover.jsx

```
'use client';

import { Popover } from '@headlessui/react'

export const PopoverGroup = Popover.group;
```

header.jsx

```
import PopoverGroup  from '../../../app/ClientPopover'

<PopoverGroup>
   ...
</PopoverGroup>
```

This is the error I'm getting:

[image]

```
Error: Element type is invalid. Received a promise that resolves to: undefined. Lazy element type must resolve to a class or function.
```

Comment: Here is the 3rd party component i'm using: https://headlessui.com/react/popover#grouping-related-popovers

Comment: `import PopoverGroup` -> `import {PopoverGroup}`